# Phantom characters with the Cocoa text system

Tags: macos, cocoa, text, view

I'm in the planning stages of a Mac OS X plain text editor app, and I need to determine at what level I need to customize the text system to achieve something like the following. This is somewhat related to the problem of syntax highlighting, but one thing makes it very different.

The behavior of this plain text editor would be special. It would asynchronously parse the text at the same time the user edits the document, and at certain positions in the text it would insert structure-indicating marks in the text as the user types. These phantom marks would look like regular (maybe differently colored) characters, *but they are not part of the actual text.*

For instance, think of a text editor that teaches children the order of operations of arithmetic. The user would type in a math expression like 3+8*3/9, and the user would instead see 3+((8*9)/9) in the text view; parentheses would appear at the same time she types. The parentheses would be phantom marks and would not be selectable, and copying the text would not include them either. Using the left and right arrow keys would skip them (e.g. the caret can never be at the left side of a "(" or the right side of a ")".). Trying to delete them would result in instead deleting the next character before it. They in short would be under the total control of the app's parser.

So conceptually, the data model is a plain text string that the user edits and a list of locations of phantom characters that the parser computes and regenerates. The problem is combining these two components into a text view that behaves as in the example above.

I am unfamiliar with Cocoa programming in general. In your experience, how practical would it be implement the above without resorting to Core Text? Is it possible by replacing some delegate or subclassing NSTextLayout or something?

I don't want my text views to do weird shapes or anything. I just want them to display characters that aren't part of the actual text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually have an app that does something very similar.

I subclassed `NSTextView` and overrode `-drawRect:`, using `NSLayoutManager` and this code...

```
NSRect rectOfChars = [[textView layoutManager]boundingRectForGlyphRange: [[textView layoutManager]glyphRangeForCharacterRange:arange actualCharacterRange:NULL] inTextContainer:[textView textContainer]];
```

...to get the `NSRect`(s) to draw my markers.

I then implemented `-textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementString:` in my text view's delegate to adjust the markers appropriately when the user edits text.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at NSLayoutManager, specifically `-drawGlyphsForGlyphRange:atPoint:`